# Ionic push service returns 301

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to send push notifications to my iphone. I followed the instructions exactly as on the Ionic website, but when I do a CURL post to my app, the result is 301. Is there anything I have to do beside the instructions on their website listed [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch)

It looks like a certificate problem, but for as I know I have a valid certificate for development purposes..

Answer (score 0):

Sloppy. I was running the IOS project in production mode..